# Convert string from mysql database in one run of while loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, while-loop

I used explode to take an array of photo file names and put them into a string so that I can store them in a mysql database, they are stored in a field called 'imagesordered' like this :
329722360536.jpeg,278255684690.jpeg,813207971421.jpg 
so they are separated using commas.

So far I have the following to pull them out of the database :

```
    include("connect.php");
    $sql = <<<SQL
        SELECT *
        FROM `albumorders`
    SQL;


    if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $albumid = $row['albumid'];
        $albumname = $row['albumname'];
        $imagesordered = $row['imagesordered'];

        }
```

The problem is that I am only echoing out the string, what I need it to do is echo out each of the values on a separate line minus the commas, but with only one run of the while loop, as each record has so many photos associated with it, so ideally on each run of the while loop I would get :

```
Album Id : 34n3jn43n
Album Name : Bobs album
Album Orders :
3433434.jpg
3434343.jpg
3434343.jpg
2323243.jpg
```

and then onto the next record......

but im not sure how to go about doing it ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $albumid = $row['albumid'];
    $albumname = $row['albumname'];
    $imagesordered = $row['imagesordered'];

    $img_arrary = explode(',',$imagesordered);      

    echo 'Album Id : '.$albumid."<br>";
    echo 'Album Name :'.$albumname."<br>";
    echo 'Album Orders :<br>';
    foreach($img_arrary as $key=>$value)
    {
        echo $value."<br>"; 
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $albumid = $row['albumid'];
    $albumname = $row['albumname'];
    $imagesordered = $row['imagesordered'];
    $imageArr = explode(',',$imagesordered);
    foreach($imageArr as $images){
       echo $images;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kasun Rajapaksha is onto it

be checky and add `<br>` tags to each, but forget the loop:

`$imagesordered = str_replace(',', '<br>', $row['imagesordered']);`